# SocketIO data to VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io

How can I place data results from socketIO to the Vue instance ? This is my code:

```
let socket = io();
let users;

socket.on('user-connected', (data) => {
    users = data.count;
});
socket.on('user-disconnected', (data) => {
    console.log(data.count);
});

new Vue({
    el: '#playersCounter',
    data: {
        playerCounter: users
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-start" id="playersCounter">
    <p class="onlinePlayersCounter">Online: {{playerCounter}}</p>
</div>
```

At the moment I get no errors and also data is not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
let socket = io();

new Vue({
    el: '#playersCounter',
    data: {
        playerCounter: users
    },
    created: function() {
        socket.on('user-connected', (data) => {
            this.playerCounter = data.count;
            console.log(data.count);
        });
        socket.on('user-disconnected', (data) => {
            this.playerCounter = data.count;
            console.log(data.count);
        });
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept your answer in 3 min. BTW what does `created` do  ?

Comment: created() is a life cycle function. It is called then the Vue instance is created. You can find all life cycle functions here:
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram